# Property Rows.Count of HtmlTable reduced to 1

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, html-table

on my `ASP.NET` page I have declared a HtmlTable as follows.

```
   <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <table id="nodesTable" runat="server" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" RULES=NONE FRAME=BOX>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

I fill my table as follows:

```
For i As Integer = 0 To 15 Step 1
          Dim tblRow As New HtmlTableRow
          tblInnerCell = New HtmlTableCell()
          Dim htmlCb As New HtmlControls.HtmlInputCheckBox
          tblInnerCell.Style.Add("text-align", "center")
          tblInnerCell.Controls.Add(htmlCb)
          tblRow.Cells.Add(tblInnerCell)
          nodesTable.Rows.Add(tblRow) 'Debugging here show the rowCount increase to sa far as 15
Next
```

So I see 15 checkboxes and the html code shows 15 rows.
Then I check one of my checkboxes as 'checked' and press a button.

The code behind of my button

```
    For Each row As HtmlTableRow In nodesTable.Rows
           If(CBool(CType(row.Cells(0).Controls(0), HtmlInputCheckBox).Checked))
           ....
           End If
    Next
```

But all of a sudden `nodesTable.Rows.Count = 1`

Why is that?

Comment: All controls are disposed and you need to create them on every postback if added programmatically. You could use a `Repeater` or `GridView` to achieve the same much easier.

Comment: @TimSchmelter : thanks for the info. I didn't realise that the controls would be disposed of.